# Validation error in label for HTML radio buttons

Tags: validation

I have a validation error in my HTML form, where there are radio buttons (appleiphonebuyers.com/sell.html). Error reads:

Line 155, Column 44: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.

```
… <label for="condition" class="inline"><span class="formstar">*</span> Conditi…
```

Is there another way I should apply a label to the group of radio buttons besides using "label for"?

UPDATE:

Here is the HTML for those radio buttons:

```
<LABEL class="inline" for="condition"><SPAN class="formstar">*</SPAN> Condition</LABEL> <INPUT class="conditionselect" type="radio" name="condition" value="Good" />Good <INPUT class="conditionselect" type="radio" name="condition" value="Okay" />Okay <INPUT class="conditionselect" type="radio" name="condition" value="Bad" />Bad <BR />
```

It just occurred to me that maybe I have to change the INPUT class to "condition" so it's the same as the "label for" attribute? I thought it was the name that had to be the same but maybe it's the class? –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there another way I should apply a label to the group of radio buttons besides using "label for"?

A `<label>` labels a *single* form control, not a group of them.

Use `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` for a group of font controls.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend> Condition </legend>
    <input type="radio" name="condition" id="condition_1" value="1"> 
        <label for="condition_1"> 1 </label>
    <input type="radio" name="condition" id="condition_2" value="12> 
        <label for="condition_2"> 2 </label>
    <input type="radio" name="condition" id="condition_3" value="13> 
        <label for="condition_3"> 3 </label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a typo on it, the FOR attribute should always be exactly the same as in the ID.

Other than that I don't see nothing wrong. You'd have to feed us some more HTML to be able to help more thoroughly.

Comment: there is no typo. I'll try posting some html tomorrow. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The for atribute must map to the input element's ID, and not its name.